# if statement, how do you stop the program from continuing to read past the first correct if or else if statement

Tags: c#, winforms

in an `if else` statements,  the program also reads the second statement even though it is not used.

The second statement `else if` contains a link to a WPF form for printing. Even though it is not used because the first `if` statement is used, it still picks up the coding in the WPF and resides the window forms to a very small form.

I need to stop the program from reading the else if statement.

```
private void btnPrintPies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtPiesRecID == null || dgvPies.CurrentCell == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is no recipe to print", "Error");
        this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage11;

    }
    else if (txtPiesRecID != null || dgvPies.CurrentCell != null)
    {
        SetValueForPrRecID = txtPiesRecID.Text;
        PtRecipe window = new PtRecipe();
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `else if` works as it should: only when previous `if` was false. more likely your conditions are wrong

Comment: negation of `(txtPiesRecID == null || dgvPies.CurrentCell == null)` will be `(txtPiesRecID != null && dgvPies.CurrentCell != null)`

Comment: Your analysis is wrong. If statements are not broken. How your analysis is wrong we cannot say without an example that we can run. Can you give us a complete short runnable program that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Also, I note that your "else if" condition is probably wrong. If txtpierecid is null and dgvpies.currentcell is not null then the condition is met because OR only requires one of the operands to be true. You'll then do null.Text inside the consequence of the else if, and crash.  Is the problem because you've written the wrong condition in the else if?

Comment: The problem I am having is: the program is picking up the information in the else if which sends you to a WPF class for printing.  Somehow it is picking up the information for resizing a WPF form which if the first (if) is correct, the program goes back to the original window form and resizes it to a small window.  If the lines in the (else if) is Commanded out the original form will not resize. Here is the program page and the WPF page.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going on here.

First of all, you are using ‘or’. If the left hand evaluates to false, it will evaluate the right hand. If the right hand is false, it will continue to walk down the statement until a condition evaluates to true.

There are two possible problems here:
One of those values is not null, hence why it walks down to the last branch.
Or your last branch is using ‘or’ when I believe you should be using &&.

If-Statements in C# short circuit when using the or operator, all it needs is one condition to be true in order to execute the code in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Because the coding in WPF interfered with window form, I converted the program to WPF with no Window Forms.  This solved the problem of the program reading the else part and resetting the forms sizes.